# VBA Automated Mailmerge using 2 templates based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, macros, ms-word

Scenario:
I have a spreadsheet used for generating letters via an automated mail merge macro. The spread typically contains about 2000 rows

Problem:
  I need to have the ability to create letters using 2 different letter templates based on cell values in a column. In the example below, the value on column C should dictate which letter template will be used for each row.

Example

```
      Col A        Col B            Col C
      John         Smith           YES           Letter Template 1 to be used
      Joe            Henricks      No            Letter Template 2  to be used
       Mark        Jones            YES          Letter Template 1  to be used
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Here is some VBA I was playing with but can't quite get it working for the 2 different letters.

I've also tried using IF, THEN, ELSE statements but still can't get it working

```
   Sub CommandButton2_Click()

   Selection.AutoFilter   '''''''''' This should filter all rows based on the YES value 
    ActiveSheet.Range("D1:AH1").AutoFilter Field:=31, Criteria1:= _
    "YES"

     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   Dim WordApp As Object
   Dim rng As Range
   Range("A1:H1").Select

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("D1:AH1"))
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select


   On Error Resume Next
   Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0

   If WordApp Is Nothing Then
   Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   End If
    ''' This should run the macro using the YESletter Template
           WordApp.Visible = False
   WordApp.Documents.Open "\\....\docs\lg\Letterbuilder\YESletter.docm""
   WordApp.Run "Module1.SaveIndividualWordFiles"


   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   Selection.AutoFilter   '''''''''' This should filter all rows        based        on        the NO value 
ActiveSheet.Range("D1:AH1").AutoFilter Field:=31, Criteria1:= _
    "Post"

   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   On Error Resume Next
   Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0

   If WordApp Is Nothing Then
   Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   End If

    ''' This should run the macro using the NOletter Template
           WordApp.Visible = False
   WordApp.Documents.Open "\\....\docs\lg\Letterbuilder\NOletter.docm"
   WordApp.Run "Module1.SaveIndividualWordFiles"

   End
```

Here's the IF, THEN, ELSE statement method

```
   If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LetterData").Range("AH").Value = "YES" Then

       WordApp.Visible = False
   WordApp.Documents.Open "\\....\docs\lg\Letterbuilder\YESletter.docm"
   WordApp.Run "Module1.SaveIndividualWordFiles"

   ELSE

       WordApp.Visible = False
   WordApp.Documents.Open "\\....\docs\lg\Letterbuilder\NOletter.docm"
   WordApp.Run "Module1.SaveIndividualWordFiles"

   End
```

Answer (score 1):

there are some major flaws in your code:

- to open a Word document with a given template you must use [Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840891.aspx) object [Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845011.aspx) method, instead of `Open()` one
- Word templates documents have ".dot" or ".dotx" extension, instead of ".docm" I see in your code
- set only one Word application and use it throughout your macro

  and eventually "dispose" it with
- finally, *never* use `End` statement

  just use `End Sub`

so here follows a possible code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim wordApp As Object

    Set wordApp = GetWordObject '<--| get a Word object
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| if no Word Object has been gotten then exit sub

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LetterData") '<--| reference your letter worksheet
        With Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, Range("D1:AH1").EntireColumn) '<--| reference your data range as that in referenced worksheet columns D:H used range
            CreateWordDocuments .Cells, "YES", wordApp, "\\....\docs\lg\Letterbuilder\YESletter.dotx" '<--| process "YES" documents
            CreateWordDocuments .Cells, "NO", wordApp, "\\....\docs\lg\Letterbuilder\NOletter.dotx" '<--| process "NO" documents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back and remove autofilter
    End With

    '"dispose" Word
    wordApp.Quit True '<--| quit Word and save changes to open documents
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub CreateWordDocuments(dataRng As Range, criteria As String, wordApp As Object, templateDocPath As String)
    Dim cell As Range
    With dataRng '<--| reference data range
        .AutoFilter Field:=31, criteria1:=criteria '<--| filter it on its column 31 with given criteria
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell has been filtered
            For Each cell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| loop through filtered cells
                wordApp.Documents.Add templateDocPath '<-- open the passed Word template
                wordApp.Run "Module1.SaveIndividualWordFiles" '<--| run your macro
            Next cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function GetWordObject() As Object
    Dim wordApp As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") '<--| try getting a running Word application
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") '<--| if no running instance of Word has been found then open a new one

    Set GetWordObject = wordApp '<--| return the set Word application
    wordApp.Visible = False
End Function
```

BTW:

- your `data example` mentions `Col A`, `Col B` and `Col C`, but your code uses a range form column "D" to "AH"

  I  assumed this latter
- your code has a statement with `Criteria1:="Post"`

  I assumed "YES" and "NO" as the only criteria

but all these aspects are easily settable in the proposed code

Comment: Thank you for you input. I appears to accomplish my goal however I do have a question. When I run the macro I get the following error on the line below. Any suggestion on a resolution?                                           AutoFilter method of Range class failed                                      'code'.AutoFilter Field:=31, Criteria1:=criteria '<--| filter it on its column 31 with given criteria 'code'

Comment: check for `dataRng` to have been actually set a valid `Range`. So, climbing up the _chain_ to it you must ensure that 1) the workbook where the macro resides in actually have a worksheet named after "LetterData" 2) "LetterData" worksheet has data in columns "D to AH" 3)  "LetterData" worksheet column "AH" has a header

Comment: @user1839308, did you get through it?

Comment: Good Morning.... It seems like I'm close but not quite there yet. I posted an image under the answer section of this post. Hopefully it went through. That will provide more details

. 
•I have confirmed that the LetterData sheet does contain a col named PrePost which is unde AH.
•There are 2 samples (Row 2 and Row 3). In each row col AH contains the value of Pre and Post.
•Do I need to define dataRng?
•Do I need to define criteria().

Comment: @user1839308 please confirm that 1) the workbook where the macro resides in actually has a worksheet named after "LetterData". Moreover step through your code _line by line_ (place cursor in any statement in `CommandButton2_Click` and press F8 repeatedly) and see when it errors out and tell me which line this is.

Comment: Dear @user3598756, Thank you for your great answer. Would you mind help me, with making the actual "SaveIndividualWordFiles" macro as OP didn't shared. The macro should just be a mail merge and then the word file should be saved. But I can't get it to work. However the rest of your code works like a charm.

Comment: Hi @user1839308, the same applies to you. If you see this please share your macro. It would help me, with the same problem as you had 4 year ago.