# VBA Mailmerge from Excel using more than one Word template

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

**Problem:**

I would like to create letters using 2 different letter templates based on a cell value in a column in Excel.

---

My Question is an extension to the following question:

[VBA Automated Mailmerge using 2 templates based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338384/vba-automated-mailmerge-using-2-templates-based-on-cell-value#)

---

**Example:**

In the example below, the value in column C should dictate which letter template will be used for each row. (If cell value is YES use letter template "Yes.docx" otherwise use letter template "No.docx")

[image]

**Solution proposed by @user3598756 (modified to the above example):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim wordApp As Object

    Set wordApp = GetWordObject '<--| get a Word object
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| if no Word Object has been gotten then exit sub

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<--| reference your letter worksheet
        With Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, Range("A1:C1").EntireColumn) '<--| reference your data range as that in referenced worksheet columns D:H used range
            CreateWordDocuments .Cells, "YES", wordApp, "C:\Users\camil\Desktop\YES.docx" '<--| process "YES" documents
            CreateWordDocuments .Cells, "NO", wordApp, "C:\Users\camil\Desktop\NO.docx" '<--| process "NO" documents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back and remove autofilter
    End With

    '"dispose" Word
    wordApp.Quit True '<--| quit Word and save changes to open documents
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub CreateWordDocuments(dataRng As Range, criteria As String, wordApp As Object, templateDocPath As String)
    Dim cell As Range
    With dataRng '<--| reference data range
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=criteria '<--| filter it on its column 3 with given criteria
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell has been filtered
            For Each cell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| loop through filtered cells
                wordApp.Documents.Add templateDocPath '<-- open the passed Word template
                wordApp.Run "Module1.SaveIndividualWordFiles" '<--| run your macro
            Next cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function GetWordObject() As Object
    Dim wordApp As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") '<--| try getting a running Word application
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") '<--| if no running instance of Word has been found then open a new one

    Set GetWordObject = wordApp '<--| return the set Word application
    wordApp.Visible = False
End Function
```

**Request:**

Unfortunately, the original poster of the question didn't share his "SaveIndividualWordFiles" macro.

I tried to fill in the gap with parts of the VBA I usually use to mailmerge from Word, when I only have one letter template. (Seen below)

However I can't fit the pieces together.

```
Sub Merge_To_Individual_Files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc
  StrFolder = .Path & Application.PathSeparator
  For i = 1 To .MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
    With .MailMerge
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Col A")) = "" Then Exit For
        StrName = .DataFields("Col A") & " " & .DataFields("Col C")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      If Err.Number = 5631 Then
        Err.Clear
        GoTo NextRecord
      End If
    End With
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
    StrName = Trim(StrName)
    With ActiveDocument
      .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
      .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
NextRecord:
  Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You really don't need all that circumlocution. The whole lot can be done in a single mailmerge main document that uses a simple IF field to test the column C value and modify the output accordingly. Just as simple would be to use an INCLUDETEXT field in the mailmerge main document that uses the output from column C to conditionally merge from your 'Yes' and 'No' documents. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582111/how-to-merge-entirely-different-pages-based-on-value-of-merge-field

Comment: @macropod I dit try making 5 if statements inside each other including all merge fields. It worked for me, however when I send the document to a colleague, they can't use it, since the only received the last merged letter. I tried for weeks to get i to work, and have now decided that my request would be a more reliable approach, and also the letters can more easily be edited.

Comment: That most likely has nothing to do with the IF tests but with your mailmerge execution. In any event, it's impossible to comment on the IF tests when you haven't posted anything related to that.

Comment: @macropod I read your suggestion again and tried with the "includetext" field. Once again it works perfectly on my own computer, and not when I send it to a colleague. Where the content is replaced by the last merged letter. I would still prefer the VBA approach as it will give less problems if I get i to work. Unless you have a another suggestion to solve my issues.

Comment: That strongly suggests a problem with either your colleagues: computer; or method. VBA won't necessarily overcome either and is significantly harder to maintain.